# Strange views visual behaviour

Tags: 7, views

I don't know why, but [this page](http://www.paolafurlan.com/temi) on a site that I administer messed up by itself!

I didn't touch it after it was set up and running well.
But as you can see the content now doesn't fill all the page, and I can't understand why! I tried to delete the view and do it from scratch again, but the problem is still there!

Can you help me try to understand where the error is?

Comment: Look in console ... `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'superfish'`

Comment: Do you think that something went wrong with a module? I don't even installed superfish module, and the error doesn't let me know what's wrong..please can you help me understanding how to solve it?

Comment: I think that error have nothing to do with the bad visualization, because that code affects only the menu and not the page. Any other ideas?

Comment: There's a [script.js](http://www.paolafurlan.com/sites/all/themes/likable/js/script.js?muvdw6) file in your theme calling `.superfish()`. Basically, your site looks full width when you disable browser javascript. But the views slideshow doesn't work. But if there's a javascript error on the page, it might be messing up Views Slideshow. Try changing your theme to Bartik or one of the other default ones. The homepage should look fine. To disable loading of script.js open your theme's .info file and remove the line with script.js then clear your cache.

Comment: I commented the line in the .info file, but nothing changed...Any other idea guys? Thanks